# run a command line php script from java servlet

Tags: java, php, servlets, command-line, execution

Is there any way to run a php command line script (server side) from a javaservlet?? I've been trying and I don't get any exception but the script doesn't do what it supposed it does. I don't know if I'm breaking any security rules (like applets have). I'm using this code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = null;
try
{
    process = runtime.exec("php " + "wsaa-client.php wsfe" + " wsfe");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    out.println("<h4>Runned!</h4>");
}
```

And everything look ok. Even I have a process running called: php-cgi.exe

Any help/suggestion?

Comment: What output are you getting? If you see `Runned!` then chances are the code is generating an exception. Add an `e.printStackTrace()` immediately after `out.println...` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use absolute path of both the PHP and the wsaa-client.php file.
Please also catch exception and print out the exception.